# Graphite WSGI process taking up high CPU

Tags: apache, cpu, monitoring, wsgi, graphite

Our Carbon daemon (in Graphite) takes up no more than 9% CPU on a 2-core machine. However, our Graphite webapp has shot the HTTPD usage high recently to about 95%. Out of this, we have noted that the process "wsgi:graphite" is taking up as much as 93% CPU.

Has anyone come across this problem? What is the solution? We have a lot of monitoring scripts querying graphite via the Graphite URL/Render API. This will of course increase Graphite's HTTPD activity, but we havne't made any drastic changes.

I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: It turns out that our non-drastic / few changes had shot up WSGI's CPU usage, but still surprising: Why does Graphite-WSGI use up so much CPU? (I am asking with no knowledge of WSGI)